# Proving that two links in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are not equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let the set $S$ be defined as:
$$S = \{(a_{1},a_{2} \dots, a_{n}) \mid \Sigma^{n}_{1}a^{2}_{i} = 1, a_{n} = 0\}$$
Then, let $A = \mathbb{R}^{n} - S$. Intuitively, it seems clear to me that $\pi_{1}(A,c) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, where $c$ is an arbitrary element of $A$. If this is true, how can I distinguish between curves in $A$ that are not homotopic to each other? Is there something like the crossing number that can generalize to higher dimensions that I can use for this?

For the sake of reference, my intuitions are based primarily on the arguments offered page 43 of hatcher, under the section on linking circles.

Comment: What is $\pi_1(\cdot,\cdot)$???

Comment: The [fundamental group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: Lightly thought out suggestion: Perhaps you could consider an equivalence relation such that $x \sim y$ **iff** $x_n = y_n$ and $\|x\|=\|y\|$? This reduces $S$ to a single point and $X$ to half a plane missing the $S$ point.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestion is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ is the union of two simply connected open subspaces $X_1,X_2$. WLOG we can suppose $x \in X_1$. A loop with $x$ for base point is included in $X_1$ and homotopic to the constant loop equal to $x$. Therefore $\pi_1(X,x)$ is the trivial group.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I do unfortunately think so. Why must it be that the loop is homotopic to $x$ in $X_{1}$ simply because $x \in X_{1}$?

Comment: Because $X_1$ is simply connected.

Comment: Yes, but it is not necessary that the curve only lies in $X_{1}$, right? It can be that it consists of one path in $X_{1}$, followed by a path in $X_{2}$, followed by a path back to $x$, right? Or am I the one missing something here?

Comment: How can a continuous curve have parts in two disconnected opens?

Comment: The endpoint of one can approach the starting point of the other, right?

Comment: A loop $L$ is connected. $L \cap X_1$ and $L \cap X_2$ are disjoint subspaces except if $L \subseteq X_1$ or $L \subseteq X_2$. And the last option is not possible if $x \in X_1$.

Comment: Please think about how you define « approach ».

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not think I was being very articulate. What I am basically trying to say is that it isn't necessary that $X$ can always be expressed as the union of two disjoint, simply connected subsets such that $L$ lies entirely within one of them.

Comment: $X$ IS the disjoint union of two simply connected open subspaces. Namely $X_1$ for $\{x_n>0\}$ and $X_2$ for $\{x_n<0\}$.